# Do not Integrate TestFlight SDK in Release Builds using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, app-store, cocoapods, testflight

I integrated the `TestFlight SDK` using Cocoapods with the following `Podfile`: https://gist.github.com/fabb/8841271

I do not want the TestFlight library to be linked in `Release` builds (build config, *not* target).

[This article](http://justatheory.com/computers/os/ios/integrate-testflight-sdk.html) shows a way to remove the `libTestFlight.a` file from Release builds using the `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` custom build setting.

**Is there a way I can do this using Cocoapods too?** Remember, Cocoapods does link the `libTestFlight.a` into its `libPods.a`, so setting the custom build setting in the app target will not help.

An alternative idea would be to only include the `TestFlight SDK` pod for my `TestFlightRelease` build config - but it seems this is not yet supported by Cocoapods.

Answer (score 4):

There is a suggested [workaround](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/731#issuecomment-20260358) while the feature gets implemented:

> - Create a new (empty) target of type "Static Library" named
>     "DebugTools" in your user project
> - Link it with your application, but
>     only in Debug, by adding `-lDebugTools` to the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` Build
>     Setting but only for the Debug configuration *(don't forget to keep
>     `$(inherited)` if not present already)*
>
> Then you should be able to
>   configure the pods needed in debug by adding them in the DebugTool
>   target only, via your Podfile, like:
>
> ```
> pod 'AFNetworking' # For all build configurations, Debug and Release
>
> target 'DebugTools', :exclusive => true do
>     pod 'PonyDebugger' # Debugger only needed in debug
>     pod 'OHHTTPStubs' # Stubs for Network Requests only in debug too
> end
> ```

The implementation status is updated in the same thread.

Comment: You might also have to add -all_load and remove any flags that make use of dynamic libraries. Instead add dynamic libraries in the build phases tab, otherwise it may fail.